# Making sure two transaction matrices have the same structure

Tags: r, arules

I want to calculate the lift for (previously defined / old) itemsets based on a list of new transactions. This can be done with the interestMeasure function.

```
quality(old_itemsets)$lift_ref <- interestMeasure(old_itemsets,"lift",transactions = TransMat_ref, reuse = FALSE)
```

The problem is: This doesn't work properly. I know this, because I have some itemsets consisting of only a single item. When calculating the lift in the new transactions, for these single items the lift should be equal to one but it is not!

I believe the problem might be in my pre-processing. The transactions I use for generating the itemsets and the new trensactions do not contain exactly the same items. Hence I added the the items missing in one list to the other and vice versa. Here's an example how it's done in one direction.

```
OldNames <- colnames(TransMat_old)
ReferenceNames <- colnames(TransMat_ref)

SetDiffNames <- setdiff(ReferenceNames, OldNames)

ItemsToAdd <- matrix(data = FALSE, nrow = length(TransMat_old), ncol = length(SetDiffNames))
colnames(ItemsToAdd) <- SetDiffNames

TransMat_old <- merge(TransMat_old, ItemsToAdd)
```

As I wrote above, I do this twice, so that both transaction matrices contain all items. The problem is: The missing items are just added as additional columns which means that they are not in the same order for the two matrices!

Could that be the reason my `interestMeasure` at the top does not work?

- If yes, how can I make sure both transactions matrices have the same structure with their items in the same order?
- If not, what other reason could mess up my calculation?

Thanks in advance!

### Major Edit: Here's my reproducible example

```
library(arules)

#create transactions
data <- paste(
"item1, item2, item3",
"item1, item3",
"item1, item2",
sep="\n")
cat(data)
write(data, file = "TransMat_Old")

data <- paste(
"item2, item3, item4",
"item3, item4",
"item2, item4",
"item2",
sep="\n")
cat(data)
write(data, file = "TransMat_New")

# load transactions
TransMat_Old <- read.transactions("TransMat_Old", format = "basket", sep=",") 
TransMat_New <- read.transactions("TransMat_New", format = "basket", sep=",") 

# Here's my function for adding
SameItems <- function(TransMat_Old, TransMat_New){

    OldNames <- colnames(TransMat_Old)
    NewNames <- colnames(TransMat_New)

    SetDiffNames <- setdiff(NewNames, OldNames)

    ItemsToAdd <- matrix(data = FALSE, nrow = length(TransMat_Old), ncol = length(SetDiffNames))
    colnames(ItemsToAdd) <- SetDiffNames

    TransMat_Data_allItems <- merge(TransMat_Old, ItemsToAdd)

    return(TransMat_Data_allItems)
}

# Add items from one matrix to the other and vice versa
Combined1 <- SameItems(TransMat_Old, TransMat_New)
Combined2 <- SameItems(TransMat_New, TransMat_Old)

# Find itemsets in the old matrix
itemsets <- apriori(data=Combined1, parameter=list(supp=0.1, maxlen=2, target="frequent itemsets"))
inspect(itemsets)

#Calculate Lift for the itemsets
quality(itemsets)$lift_oldSet <- interestMeasure(itemsets,"lift", transactions = Combined1, reuse = FALSE)

#Calculate lift for old itemsets based on the new transaction matrix
quality(itemsets)$lift_newSet <- interestMeasure(itemsets,"lift", transactions = Combined2, reuse = FALSE)

#Single-item-itemsets should have a lift of 1. But they have not.
inspect(itemsets)
```

**As mentioned above: single-item-itemsets should have a lift of 1 in the new dataset. But they have not.**

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: You should read `?itemCoding` in arules.

Comment: @Michael `itemCoding` certainly sounds like it can solve my problem. But to be honest I have some trouble understanding how it can be applied in my situation. Because, of the two transaction matrices I have one is not a subset of the other. They share most of their items but each matrix has items of its own. Which means I have to add empty columns to the matrices. Would you be so kind and push me in the right direction with a code snippet of how I can make sure two transaction matrices have the same items?

Comment: Provided an  reproducible example in a major edit to my opening post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get all item labels and recode the transaction sets.

```
all_item_labels <- union(itemLabels(TransMat_New),itemLabels(TransMat_Old)) 

TransMat_Old <- recode(TransMat_Old, itemLabels = all_item_labels)
TransMat_New <- recode(TransMat_New, itemLabels = all_item_labels)
```

Now both transaction sets have the same items in the same order and are compatible with each other.